# Delete Objects in a List as Passed to Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I need to pass each object in a large list to a function. After the function completes I no longer need the object passed to the function and would like to delete the object to save memory. If I were working with a single process I would do the following:

```
result = []
while len(mylist) > 0:
    result.append(myfunc(mylist.pop())
```

As I loop over mylist I pop off each object in the list such that the object is no longer stored in mylist after it's passed to my function. How do I achieve this same effect in parallel using `multiprocessing`?

Comment: With a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue)?

Answer (score 0):

A simple consumer example ([credits go here](http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html#multiprocessing-queues)) :

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import random

class Consumer(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, task_queue, result_queue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.task_queue = task_queue
        self.result_queue = result_queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            task = self.task_queue.get()
            if task is None:
                # Poison pill means shutdown
                self.task_queue.task_done()
                break
            answer = task.process()
            self.task_queue.task_done()
            self.result_queue.put(answer)
        return


class Task(object):

    def process(self):
        time.sleep(0.1) # pretend to take some time to do the work
        return random.randint(0, 100)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Establish communication queues
    tasks = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
    results = multiprocessing.Queue()

    # Start consumers
    num_consumers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2
    consumers = [Consumer(tasks, results) for i in xrange(num_consumers)]
    for consumer in consumers:
        consumer.start()

    # Enqueue jobs
    num_jobs = 10
    for _ in xrange(num_jobs):
        tasks.put(Task())

    # Add a poison pill for each consumer
    for _ in xrange(num_consumers):
        tasks.put(None)

    # Wait for all tasks to finish
    tasks.join()

    # Start printing results
    while num_jobs:
        result = results.get()
        print 'Result:', result
        num_jobs -= 1
```